# Error importing types from Spark SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to import  types from spark sql as follows

import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

But I get an errors such as: "not found: value DataType", "not found: type ByteType"

The full code is

```
import java.math.BigDecimal                                                                           
import java.sql.{Timestamp, Date}                                                                     

import org.apache.spark.sql.types._                                                                   

/**                                                                                                   
 * Utility functions for type casting                                                                 
 */                                                                                                   
object TypeCast {                                                                                     

  /**                                                                                                 
   * Casts given string datum to specified type.                                                      
   * Currently we do not support complex types (ArrayType, MapType, StructType).                      
   *                                                                                                  
   * @param datum string value                                                                        
   * @param castType SparkSQL type                                                                    
   */                                                                                                 
  def castTo(datum: String, castType: DataType): Any = {                                              
    castType match {                                                                                  
      case _: ByteType => datum.toByte                                                                
      case _: ShortType => datum.toShort                                                              
      case _: IntegerType => datum.toInt                                                              
      case _: LongType => datum.toLong                                                                
      case _: FloatType => datum.toFloat                                                              
      case _: DoubleType => datum.toDouble                                                            
      case _: BooleanType => datum.toBoolean                                                          
      case _: DecimalType => new BigDecimal(datum.replaceAll(",", ""))                                
      case _: TimestampType => Timestamp.valueOf(datum)                                               
      case _: DateType => Date.valueOf(datum)                                                         
      case _: StringType => datum                                                                     
      case _ => throw new RuntimeException(s"Unsupported type: ${castType.typeName}")                 
    }                                                                                                 
  }
```

Comment: Presumably you/re not getting the error on the import, but later. Show us the code. And the "not found: *value* DataType" suggests the compiler is not expecting a type at that point...

Comment: updated the original question

Comment: I don't get any "not found: value DataType" error, Also from a look at the source IntType etc are case objects, not types/classes.

Answer (score 3):

ByteType etc are not types, but singleton case objects.

So you probably want something like this:

```
 def castTo(datum: String, castType: DataType): Any = {                                              
    castType match {                                                                                  
      case DataType.ByteType => datum.toByte                                                                
      case DataType.ShortType => datum.toShort                                                              
      case DataType.IntegerType => datum.toInt                                                              
      case DataType.LongType => datum.toLong                                                                
      case DataType.FloatType => datum.toFloat                                                              
      case DataType.DoubleType => datum.toDouble                                                            
      case DataType.BooleanType => datum.toBoolean                                                          
      case DataType.DecimalType => new BigDecimal(datum.replaceAll(",", ""))                                
      case DataType.TimestampType => Timestamp.valueOf(datum)                                               
      case DataType.DateType => Date.valueOf(datum)                                                         
      case DataType.StringType => datum                                                                     
      case _ => throw new RuntimeException(s"Unsupported type: ${castType.typeName}")                 
    }                                                                                                 
  }
```

(except that at least in my version of Spark, there's no DecimalType, and castType doesn't have a typeName field)

Comment: Thanks! Started programming in Scala a week ago so still confused about some things. I got the code from https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/csv/util/TypeCast.scala

Comment: It really might have been a good idea to explain you were working with someone else's code.  I suggest you contact the author of that package - I don't see how it can work, at least with my version of Spark, since ByteType etc really aren't types

Comment: Might be a silly question, but how do I know if it's a Type or a singleton object?  If I have both class ByteType  and object ByteType defined. The former is a Type, the latter a singleton object....

Comment: I used a combination of seeing what my IDE said, and googling!